# Intuition about : $a = b \iff | a − b| < \epsilon$, for every $\epsilon > 0$

Tags: inequality, intuition

This is Theorem 1.2.6 in Abbott. [*Understanding Analysis* (2016 2 edn)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1493927116). pp 9 - 10. I'm NOT asking about [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3340093/85079) that the author proves. Please don't prove. I'm longing just for intuition.

1. I can't intuit how, God willing, an equality (on LHS)  can be equivalent to a conjunction of strict inequalities (on RHS).
2. Is there any picture that can assist?

Comment: If $a\neq b$, then $|a-b|$ is positive, so it cannot be smaller than all positive numbers. This is both the intuition, but also the proof.

Comment: How about this. Take a strip of paper. Tell yourself "this strip is too long", tear a part off and throw it away. Then tell yourself again "this strip is too long", tear a part off and throw it away. What will you have left over if you repeat this to infinity

Comment: Think of a microscope with resolution $\epsilon$, that is, all objects that differ less than $\epsilon$ are not distinguishable.  Now what would you say about two objects you can't distinguish  regardless which resolution you use?

Comment: The issue becomes trivial by translating it into natural language: the only non-negative number which is smaller than all positive numbers is $0$. The word "number" may refer to either real numbers or rationals. This is equivalent to "Given any positive number we can find a smaller positive number". And this can be compared with "given any positive integer, we can a greater positive integer (just by adding one to it)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Identity of Indiscernibles](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity-indiscernible/#Form) :

> If we cannot find the slightest difference between two objects $a$ and $b$, then necessarily the two must be identical.

And vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

For $x$ non-negative, $\forall \epsilon>0:x<\epsilon$ is a contrived way to say $x=0$ without saying it.

Because if $x$ is positive, you will find some $\epsilon$ that contradicts the inequality $x<\epsilon$ (for example $\epsilon=\frac x2$).

---

Note that $\forall \epsilon>0:x\le\epsilon$ also works. But not $\forall \epsilon\ge0:x<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

Smaller than anything can only be zero.

Comment: Two answers? Seriously?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta: there wasn't enough room in the short answer.

Comment: Haha good one! I'll forgive you! Have a nice day/night!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $|a-b|  < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. Thus the distance between $a$ and $b$ is smaller than every strictly positive number.

Suppose to the contrary that this distance is non-zero, then $|a-b| > 0$ and then your claim says that $|a-b| < |a-b|$, which is a contradiction.

Thus we must have that the distance $|a-b| = 0$, which only happens when $a=b$.

Drawing a picture to see what's going on will definitely help. Take two distinct points $a\neq b$. On the picture, argue why $|a-b| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ can never happen (my proof above contains the answer). So I would argue that the proof is actually the intuition.

Comment: Sorry, but I ruled out proofs  like your first 3 paras. that I already understand.

Comment: See last lines. The proof is basically the intuition.

Comment: I just drew the picture, but I'm not seeing the intuition.

Comment: Did you draw two different distinct points? Consider their distance $d$. Can the distance $d$ ever be smaller than every positive number? No, you have a problem when your positive number that you chose becomes smaller than this distance.

Comment: If I would say to you: this object is smaller than $\epsilon > 0$ meters for every $\epsilon > 0$, how large is the object? It must be smaller than $1$ meter, because $1/2 < 1$. It must also be smaller than $1/2$, because $1/4$. It must also be smaller than $1/4$ and keep doing this.