# Please check my proof for : Prove $|x| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ iff $x = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I've recently started studying Real Analysis by myself, not going to any school at the moment. I need some help to review my answer below.

### Question from  Exercise 2.12 of [this PDF](http://www.math.louisville.edu/%7Elee/RealAnalysis).

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove $|x| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ iff $x = 0$.

### Answer

Suppose for contradiction that $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $|x| \geq \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.
$|x| = |x - \epsilon + \epsilon| \leq |x - \epsilon| + |\epsilon|$ by Triangle inequality.
Since the first term ($|x - \epsilon| \geq 0$) and by our assumption ($\forall \epsilon > 0$), this contradicts $|x| \geq \epsilon$.

### Comment

I am not sure if my answer is solid enough to lead to the contradiction.

### Edit

Thank you for all the questions! I stepped towards the wrong direction from the beginning!  I will try myself to prove that there is an arbitrary $\epsilon$ which can take the value below $|x|$ unless $|x| = 0$, based on $\forall \epsilon > 0$.

Comment: You negated wrong

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Did you mean this part? $|x| = |x - \epsilon + \epsilon|$. Can also you help me to fix it??

Comment: Contradiction would be $|x|\ge\epsilon$ for *some* $\epsilon>0$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, Thank you for mentioning the critical mistake! I was checking the difference of for_all vs for_some and it seems that in this question, I shouldn't use it for the starter, doesn't it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition: If $a\leq b+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon&gt;0$ then $a\leq b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679038/intuition-if-a-leq-b-epsilon-for-all-epsilon0-then-a-leq-b)

Comment: @user1110341 Again: this target cannot be used to close various and distinct (thow somehow related) questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition about : $a = b \iff | a − b| &lt; \epsilon$, for every $\epsilon &gt; 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3436553/intuition-about-a-b-iff-a-%e2%88%92-b-epsilon-for-every-epsilon-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x=0$ then certainly, $|x|=|0|=0<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

Now, you want to show that if for all $\epsilon>0$ , $|x|<\epsilon$ then, $x=0$.
Suppose $x\neq 0$ so $|x|>0$. Hence, for $\epsilon=|x|$, $|x|<|x|$. Contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Let me take time to digest this!!

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove that

$$(\forall x\in \Bbb R)\;\;\Bigl( (\forall \epsilon>0)\; \; |x|<\epsilon\;\; \iff \;\; x=0\Bigr)$$

Proof

Let $ x\in \Bbb R$ such that
$$(\forall \epsilon>0) \;\; |x|<\epsilon$$

Assume $ x\ne 0$.

$$x\ne 0 \implies |x|>0$$

$$\implies \;\; \exists \epsilon(=\frac{|x|}{2})>0 \;\; : \;\; |x|>\epsilon $$
which contradicts the hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Let me take time to digest this!!

Answer (score 1):

If $x = 0$, the result follows. Suppose otherwise that $|x| < \varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$ and $x\neq 0$. Then either $x > 0$ or $x < 0$. In the first case $(x > 0)$, one can choose $\varepsilon = x/2$, whence we get
\begin{align*}
|x| = x < \varepsilon = \frac{x}{2} \Longleftrightarrow x < 0 
\end{align*}
which leads to a contradiction. Similarly, if $x < 0$, we can choose $\varepsilon = -x/2$, whence we get that
\begin{align*}
|x| = -x < \varepsilon =  -\frac{x}{2} \Longleftrightarrow x > 0
\end{align*}
which is also a contradiction. Consequently, $x = 0$ and we are done.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Let me take time to digest this!!

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $x \neq 0$. Then, $|x| = c >0$. Set $\epsilon <c$ for example, $\epsilon = \frac{c}{2}$. Then we have $c = |x|  < \epsilon = c/2$ by assumption, meaning that $c < c/2$. But this of course cannot happen.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Let me take time to digest this!!